# Curl and Python requests.post returning different outputs

Tags: python, http, curl, post

I am trying to make a call to one of my services using python. For some reason the responses look different:

Curl command:

```
curl -X POST --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: text/plain" -d 'Machine Learning is my favorite field' http://localhost:30086/cs/tokenizer?lemmatizeTokens=true&useStrictDomainFiltering=false
```

Python code:

```
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
params = {'lemmatizeTokens': str(true).lower(), 'useStrictDomainFiltering': str(false).lower()}
url = 'http://localhost:30086/cs/tokenizer'
articleBody = 'Machine Learning is my favorite field'
data = {'articleBody': articleBody}
print(articleBody)
print(data)
r = requests.post(url, data = data, headers = headers, params=params)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.text)
    return r.json(), 200
else:
    return 'Unknown error occurred while processing tokens', 500
```

They should be returning the exact same output, but the curl command returns:
{"field":1,"machine_learning":1,"favorite":1}

And the python code returns:
{"field":1,"learn":1,"machine":1,"favorite":1}

The CURL output is correct, so is there any difference in the calls between the two? It would seem as the input is getting parsed word by word on the python code.

Thanks.

Comment: The CURL request does not use a key name `articleBody` when it sends the data `Machine Learning is my favorite field`.

Comment: Bingo. Please post your comment as a response so I can accept it as the correct answer. And thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CURL request does not use a key name `articleBody` when it sends the data `Machine Learning is my favorite field`.